# Common code in React component constructor and componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I often come to this sort of situation when using statefull React components.

I need to do some operation on props - either do some processing which I do now want to have in `render()` or set state according the values in props.

As I want to do this when component is initially mounted as well as when the props are updated, I end up with a boilerplate code like this:

```
constructor(){
    super(props)
    const modifiedProps = doSomethingWithProps(props)
        ...
    this.state = {initialState}
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const modifiedProps = doSomethingWithProps(nextProps)
         ...
    this.setState({newState})
}

doSomethingWithProps(props){
        ...
}
```

Is there a better way how to do this ?

Comment: if you are not setting state, you can use `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor`

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't use `constructor` for this, `componentWillMount`, is usually where I put all my code for this kind of thing.

Comment: @TryingToImprove Is `componentDid/WillMount` called even when the props are just updated ?

Comment: "Better" how? That's a fairly canonical way to extract functionality.

Comment: That is a boilerplate for me and one which happens quite often.

Comment: @dev-null no, it will not.

Answer (score 2):

Answering based on the question's comments, which I found quite helpful --

If there's a bunch of work that needs to be done based on `props`, `componentWillMount` allows you to use `this.setState()` in your helper functions and minimize the work that's done in the `constructor`.  This can clean up a bunch of otherwise duplicated code.

```
constructor(){
    super(props)
    this.state = {initialState}
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.doSomethingWithProps(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.doSomethingWithProps(nextProps)
}

doSomethingWithProps(props){
    ...
    this.setState({newState})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the props to the component after they are transformed?

This can be achieved in a couple of ways:

1. Use a simple stateless container, which transforms the props and passes them to this component.

   ```
   export const Container = (props) =>
       <YourComponent modifiedProp={doSomethingWithProps(props)} />
   ```
2. Use a [connected component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) and do the transformation inside the `mapStateToProps` method:

   ```
   const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
       modifiedProp: doSomethingWithProps(ownProps)
   });

   export const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
   ```

The first option is really a stripped-down version of the second.

You may also be interested in using [selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to compute the derived props that you pass to your component.